# Calculate the Exponential of a Matrix

Tags: matrices, symplectic-linear-algebra

Let $F_r(l)=e^{A_r(l)}=[f_{r,ij}]$, where $A_r(l)=\begin{bmatrix}-r&r\\-r&r-l\end{bmatrix}$, where $r>0,l>0$.

1. Calculate $F_r(l)$. (Analytic expression or approximation, in terms of series, if possible).
2. Show that $f_{r,12}+f_{r,21}=0$.

The original questions is the following:
Let $A_r(A)=\begin{bmatrix} -rI&rI\\-rI&(r-1)I+A \end{bmatrix}$, where
$A,I$ are of the same dimension and $I$ is the identity matrix. Calculate the coefficients for $A,A^2,A^3,\cdots$ in the expansion of $e^{A_r(A)}$.

Comment: What have you tried so far? It is more likely that you would get help from the community if you also post your work and specify where exactly you are stuck.

Comment: I tried the expansion of a expontial, i.e. $e^x=\sum_{j=0}^\infty x^j/(j!)$, but in vain. Only guess that $f_{r,12}+f_{r,21}=0$. So far not much progress.

Comment: Please edit the answer to include your efforts there otherwise your question is at risk of being closed.

Comment: @LostBird It would be helpful if you could take that comment and edit it into your post after the question statement.

Comment: @LostBird Also, what inspired you to ask this question? Do you have a reason to believe that part 1 has a "nice" answer (for example, was this part of a homework assignment)?

Comment: The command of Mathematica `MatrixExp[{{-r, r}, {-r, r - l}}]` does the job. The first element of the first row is $$\frac{e^{\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{l} \sqrt{l-4 r}-\frac{l}{2}} \left(\sqrt{l} \sqrt{l-4 r}+l-2 r\right)}{2 \sqrt{l} \sqrt{l-4 r}}-\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{l} \sqrt{l-4 r}-\frac{l}{2}} \left(-\sqrt{l} \sqrt{l-4 r}+l-2 r\right)}{2 \sqrt{l} \sqrt{l-4 r}} .$$

Comment: This answer is very near to what I want, @user64494. Also I put the original question here. Let $A_r(A)=\begin{bmatrix} -rI&rI\\-rI&(r-1)I+A \end{bmatrix}$, where $I$ is the identity matrix and $A$ is a matrix with the same dimensions, $r>0$. I would like to expand $e^{A_r(A)}$ and calculate the coefficient of $A,A^2,A^3,\cdots$. Any help?

Comment: @LostBird: Sorry, your $$ A_r(A)=\begin{bmatrix} -rI&rI\\-rI&(r-1)I+A \end{bmatrix}$$ is simply meaningless.